# yield equivelant from Rails

Tags: php, ruby

I want to have a standard layout for all my pages on my php site. Is there anything in php similar to Rails's yield

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--STYLESHEETS AND SUCH HERE-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--NAVBAR HERE-->
        <?php
            //YIELD THINGY HERE
        ?>
         <!--FOOTER HERE-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're looking for a template framework. There are loads out there.  [This article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/17/getting-started-with-php-templating-2/) is a good overview with a few examples